# Negative baseline in RTABMAP with OAK camera

Tags: ros, slam, rtabmap-ros

I have an [OAK-D Pro W PoE](https://shop.luxonis.com/collections/oak-cameras-1/products/oak-d-pro-w-poe?variant=43905979089119) camera and I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoHandHeldMapping#Bring-up_example_with_DepthAI_OAK-D) to perform SLAM with RTABMAP in ROS noetic. I follow all steps but I receive the following error message when I launch rtabmap.launch

```
[ERROR] [1703160156.148481967]: The stereo baseline (-0.075033) should be positive (baseline=-Tx/fx). We assume a horizontal left/right stereo setup where the Tx (or P(0,3)) is negative in the right camera info msg.
```

I don't know why RTABMAP reads a negative measure of the baseline.

I tried to swap left and right camera_info files in the parameters of rtabmap.launch and it starts but obviously it is not accurate.

How can I provide the right baseline?

Answer (score 0):

The third value inside the P matrix of the camera_info may be inverted between the topics, or just set without the right sign.